# Is it possible to get rid of `Root` and have an explicit closed-form solution for the given equation?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, parametric-functions

I want to solve the given equation for `m>0` where all parameters are `Reals` and `a<0`. Using `Solve` the results are in terms of `Root`; is there any way to get rid of this `Root` and have an explicit closed-form solution?

```
Solve[(s^6 + 16 s^5 m + 4 (25 - 2 d) s^4 m^2 + 
    16 s^3 m^3 (19 - 6 d + a  m) + 
    16 s^2 m^4 (28 + (-26 + d) d + 8 a  m) + 
    64 s  m^5 (4 + 2 (-6 + d) d - a (-6 + d) m) + 
    64 m^6 (4 (-2 + d) d - 4 a (-2 + d) m + a^2 m^2)) == 0, m, Reals]

(* {{m -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[s^6 + 
       16 s^5 #1 + (100 s^4 - 8 d s^4) #1^2 + (304 s^3 - 
          96 d s^3) #1^3 + (448 s^2 - 416 d s^2 + 16 d^2 s^2 + 
          16 a s^3) #1^4 + (256 s - 768 d s + 128 d^2 s + 
          128 a s^2) #1^5 + (-512 d + 256 d^2 + 384 a s - 
          64 a d s) #1^6 + (512 a - 256 a d) #1^7 + 64 a^2 #1^8 &, 1],
     OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[1]]}, {m -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[s^6 + OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[7] + 64 a^2 #1^8 &, 2], 
    OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[1]]}, {m -> OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[
   1]}, OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[
 3], {m -> OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[1]}, {m -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    Root[s^6 + 
       16 s^5 #1 + (100 s^4 - 8 d s^4) #1^2 + (304 s^3 - 
          96 d s^3) #1^3 + (448 s^2 - 416 d s^2 + 16 d^2 s^2 + 
          16 a s^3) #1^4 + (256 s - 768 d s + 128 d^2 s + 
          128 a s^2) #1^5 + (-512 d + 256 d^2 + 384 a s - 
          64 a d s) #1^6 + (512 a - 256 a d) #1^7 + 64 a^2 #1^8 &, 8],
     OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[1]]}} *)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Sadly, no. Due to [Abel-Rufini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), there is no closed form solution for _general_ polynomials with degree higher than four. Your polynomial is of order 8.

Comment: As you will know, machine numbers are not accurate. On the contrary Root is an accurate number. If MMA gives a solution in terms of Root objects, it is an accurate answer. If you want to get an inaccurate answer in term of machine numbers, you can use the function "N".

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for some values of the parameters.

```
Reduce[(s^6 + 16  s^5  m + 4  (25 - 2  d)  s^4  m^2 + 
 16  s^3  m^3  (19 - 6  d + a   m) + 
 16  s^2  m^4  (28 + (-26 + d)  d + 8  a   m) + 
 64  s   m^5  (4 + 2  (-6 + d)  d - a  (-6 + d)  m) + 
 64  m^6  (4  (-2 + d)  d - 4  a  (-2 + d)  m + a^2  m^2)) == 0, 
  m, Reals] // ToRadicals
```

results in the output which takes 5 MB in memory. In particular, the output includes a piece

> `(a == 0 && (m == (3*s + Sqrt[s^2 + 4*d*s^2])/ (4*(-2 + d)) || m == (s + Sqrt[s^2 + 4*d*s^2])/(4*d) ||  m == (s - Sqrt[s^2 + 4*d*s^2])/(4*d) || m == -1/4*s ||  m == -1/4*s))`

Also

```
s = 1; a = -2; d = 1/2; 
Reduce[(s^6 + 16  s^5  m + 4  (25 - 2  d)  s^4  m^2 + 
 16  s^3  m^3  (19 - 6  d + a   m) + 
 16  s^2  m^4  (28 + (-26 + d)  d + 8  a   m) + 
 64  s   m^5  (4 + 2  (-6 + d)  d - a  (-6 + d)  m) + 
 64  m^6  (4  (-2 + d)  d - 4  a  (-2 + d)  m + a^2  m^2)) == 0, 
  m, Reals] // ToRadicals
```

> `m == 1/4 (1 - Sqrt[3]) || m == 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[3]) ||  m == Root[-1 - 12 # - 56 #^2 - 128 #^3 - 148 #^4 - 80 #^5 + 32 #^6& , 1, 0] ||  m == Root[-1 - 12 # - 56 #^2 - 128 #^3 - 148 #^4 - 80 #^5 + 32 #^6& , 2, 0]`

In most cases, as @Domen explains, the `Root` construction cannot be reduced.

Addition. The command

```
Reduce[(s^6 + 16  s^5  m + 4  (25 - 2  d)  s^4  m^2 + 
  16  s^3  m^3  (19 - 6  d + a   m) + 
  16  s^2  m^4  (28 + (-26 + d)  d + 8  a   m) + 
  64  s   m^5  (4 + 2  (-6 + d)  d - a  (-6 + d)  m) + 
  64  m^6  (4  (-2 + d)  d - 4  a  (-2 + d)  m + a^2  m^2)) == 0 &&
a < 0, m, Reals] // ToRadicals
```

results in 1.7 MB. The output includes a piece

> `(s == 0 &&  ((d < 0 && a < 0 && (m == 0 ||  m == (2*(-2*a + a*d - Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[2*a^2 - a^2*d]))/a^2 ||  m == (2*(-2*a + a*d + Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[2*a^2 - a^2*d]))/a^2)) ||  (d == 0 && a < 0 && (m == 0 || m == -8/a)) ||  (Inequality[0, Less, d, Less, 2] && a < 0 &&  (m == 0 || m == 0 ||  m == (2*(-2*a + a*d + Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[2*a^2 - a^2*d]))/a^2)) ||  (d >= 2 && a < 0 && m == 0)))`

Also

```
s = 0;Reduce[(s^6 + 16   s^5   m + 4   (25 - 2   d)   s^4   m^2 + 
  16   s^3   m^3   (19 - 6   d + a    m) + 
  16   s^2   m^4   (28 + (-26 + d)   d + 8   a    m) + 
  64   s    m^5   (4 + 2   (-6 + d)   d - a   (-6 + d)   m) + 
  64   m^6   (4   (-2 + d)   d - 4   a   (-2 + d)   m + 
     a^2   m^2)) == 0 && a < 0, m, Reals] // ToRadicals
```

> `a < 0 && ((d <  0 && (m == 0 ||  m == (2 (-2 + d))/a - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-((-2 + d)/a^2)] ||  m == (2 (-2 + d))/a +  2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-((-2 + d)/a^2)])) || (d ==  0 && (m == 0 || m == 4 Sqrt[1/a^2] - 4/a)) || (0 < d <  2 && (m == (2 (-2 + d))/a - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-((-2 + d)/a^2)] ||  m == 0 ||  m == (2 (-2 + d))/a +  2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-((-2 + d)/a^2)])) || (d >= 2 && m == 0))`

Comment: (–1). The question clearly states $a<0$.

Comment: @Domen : Did you pay you attention to the added case `s = 1; a = -2; d = 1/2; `, where `m == 1/4 (1 + Sqrt[3])`?

Comment: @Domen: I took into account the condition `a<0` in edited answer of me.

Comment: Thanks, but anyway, I was looking for a general answer, not particular solutions.